# css lightbox remove with click?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

So, making the Lightbox appear is quite easy. but i want it to be removed if i click elsewhere or on the **TRIGGER** again. is that something that is achievable in css?
JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/tgs8fp9v/

HTML:

```
<a href="#x1">
TRIGGER
  </a>
  <a href="#" id="x1"></a>
  <div class="Info">
    message
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #x1{
  position: absolute;
  margin-top:calc(25% + 30px);
  margin-left:calc(50% - 280px);

}
#x1:hover{
zoom:1.0101;
}
#x1:target {
    outline: none;
    display: block;
}
#x1:target + .Info {
    display: block;
}
.Info{
    display:none;
    height:50px;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:99999999;
    margin-top:calc(20% - 50px);
    margin-left:calc(50% - 250px);
    border:2px solid #88d8d8;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do so with another trigger. When the user clicks another trigger, it removes the trigger pseudo class from the first one (in this case, x1)

http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/c16zavjz/

```
<a href="#x1">TRIGGER</a>
<a href="#" id="x1"></a>
<div class="Info">message</div><br>
<a href="#x2">TRIGGER2</a> <!-- or any other id -->
```

Your CSS can remain the same.

This is non-conventional, and not directly obvious if you're going to be sharing your code. The pattern is usually to use javaScript to remove an active class from all in a class, then add an active class a specific member by id or index.

Comment: thanks! Yeah, but the whole point of this lightbox was that it was supposed to be 100% css :)

Comment: @Joel This answer is 100% HTML/CSS, I'm just suggesting it not be. See the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/c16zavjz/

Comment: @Joel If you have any other questions let me know.